# GPG Verify signature with public key

Tags: cryptography, gnupg, signing

I have a file sent to me from a client. The file is being encrypted with public key and I have the private/public key pair, so I can decrypt and read it. We use GPG. Recently, the client started signing the file and gave me the new public key that is being used. However if I try to verify the file using

`gpg --verify path/to/public/key.asc /path/to/encrypted/file`

I get an error which is...gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error

There is a high possibility that I'm doing something wrong, however conceptually I think I'm missing a few points.

1. Is there a way to verify the signature of an encrypted file using the provided public key ?
2. If new public key is used for signing/encryption I guess I'm going to need a new private key for the decryption? Or is it a valid scenario to use one public key for encryption and another for signing?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm struggling with. I just don't understand why it doesn't work! Tried to follow this guide but I guess it leaves out some "banal" steps, assuming everyone knows it: https://infra.apache.org/release-signing#verifying-signature

Comment: Here's this answer, the step by step breakdown helps:
https://serverfault.com/questions/896228/how-to-verify-a-file-using-an-asc-signature-file